# C++ - How to inform that a data field is not used or set?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have an `std::vector<T>` where `T` is a type composed of small numeric fields such as `ints` or `floats`; let's say that I have a total of `4` fields for my `T`, so for example in `T` I have an `int`, a `uint32_t`, a `double` and a `float`.

Sometimes I need all 4, sometimes I only need 1 and all the others are not needed or I can easily discard them since they are at their "default value" ( `0` or `0.0` ) when I read them.

There is a way to design my type `T` such as when I'll insert a new set of values I can flag the unused field as *unused* ?

Obviously my problem is that I can't use a different `T` for each combination ( also it would be a crazy thing to do for each combination ) and I would like to combine a compact structure ( without spending even time on the insertion of a value that I'm not using ) with a common type for every scenario so the user just checks if that record is used or not.

Is this possible in standard C++ 11 or C++ 03 ?

Comment: If you can use `boost`, you could have `T` store `boost::optional<int>` etc. IIRC there will be an `std::optional` in C++14 too.

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do? WHy do you think you want to discard "unused" values?

Comment: @doctorlove there is an implicit information in a field that is not set, the user can make an assumption on the semantic of the kind of information, for example if I tell you that I never had to go to a bank you can assume that I don't have a bank account, it's something along this lines, and is something that simplifies my approach.

Comment: @juanchopanza interesting C++14 solution, boost::optional is an header-only library ?

Comment: Yes, it is header only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you hint at is an optional type. You might want to redesign your architecture, so that you don't need to store the unnecessary values. However, if you still wish to do so, there are:

- [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html)
- [Poco::Optional](http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.Optional.html)
- [a c++11 implementation of std::optional](https://github.com/RobertLeahy/optional/blob/master/optional)

If you don't want to use something like

```
std::vector< optional<T> >
```

from a library, you could use [std::pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) from the standard library

```
std::vector< std::pair<T,bool> >
```

and [std::optional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) should be available in the [head development version of Clang](http://blog.llvm.org/2013/09/libc-and-c1y.html).

Comment: there is an implicit value in expressing my `T` this way, a field that is not set is an implicit information given the kind of data that the user expects, it also simplifies the design, at least in terms of combinations of `T`. I'll take a look in those libs.

Comment: updated with a link to a `std::optional` 1-header implementation

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Every field is used, by definition.

If you don't need a field for some instances of a class then you have a few alternatives. For example:

1. Use a **specific value** which has a special meaning. For example: "If
   someone has age -1, it means that I don't know their age or that it
   is not relevant."
2. Use an **additional boolean field** `is_X_used` which
   actually stores whether field X is used or not. Then, in your
   program logic, use that field in the appropriate places. This is not
   a design which I recommend, but in some very specific cases it may
   be justified.
3. A **pointer**. You could have an `int*` field instead of an `int`. If the pointer is NULL, the value is not used. Otherwise, it is.

Comment: the third point will be great, but I need to find a solution to keep the locality, it's an interesting approach but I have to see how this scale.

Comment: in point 3 how do you want to clean up? Point 2 is something like the `std::pair` solution. Point 1 is quite unsafe

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov The OP is responsible for using any alternative wisely. About cleanup, you can, for example, follow a RAII approach: use the object's destructor to clean up resources.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the way I'd do it is to add an unsigned-int (or perhaps unsigned-char or unsigned-short) field that works as a bit-chord, with one bit corresponding to each of the other member values in the object.  Then in order to see if the nth member value is valid, you'd check the nth bit:

```
class MyData 
{
public:
   MyData() : _validBits(0) {}

   enum {
      VALID_BIT_NAME = 0,
      VALID_BIT_RANK,
      VALID_BIT_SERIAL_NUMBER,
      NUM_VALID_BITS
   };

   // whichMember should be a VALID_BIT_* value
   bool IsMemberItemValid(unsigned int whichMember) const 
   {
      return ((_validBits & (1<<whichMember)) != 0);
   }

   // whichMember should be a VALID_BIT_* value
   void SetMemberItemValid(unsigned int whichMember, bool isValid)
   {
      unsigned int bit = (1<<whichMember);
      if (isValid) _validBits |= bit;
              else _validBits &= ~bit;
   }

   unsigned int _validBits;

   std::string _name;
   int _rank;
   int _serialNumber;
};
```

Comment: very C-ish, works but more like a C function than a C++ type, and adapting this to a C++ class with iterators and constructors can be quite complex and generate some gibrish-source-code

Comment: what's a `std::String`? Why all these bit shifts when you have the standard library?

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov Why the quibbling?  Bit-shifting works fine in C++.  If you want to do it in a more standard-library-ish style, nothing is stopping you.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner just quibbling. I like writing less code. I'd wish people would write less code for correctly solving the same problem as they usually do, since it might help minimize bug occurrence